# Can i use `SET` variable in sequelize in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Can i use `SET` variable in sequelize in nodejs?

**Sequelize**

**Model**

**Session Model**

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Sessions = sequelize.define(
    "sessions",
    {
      id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
      challenge_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "challenges",
          key: "id"
        },
        allowNull: false
      },
      createdAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
      createdBy: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "users",
          key: "id"
        },
        allowNull: false
      },
      showAtLeaderboard: { type: DataTypes.ENUM("yes", "no") },
      sessionFile: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      score: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
      underscored: true
    }
  );
  return Sessions;
};
```

**Challenge Model**

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Challenges = sequelize.define(
    "challenges",
    {
      id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
      song_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
      challenge_name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      challengeDescription: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      challengeImg: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      challengeType: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      coins: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
      createdAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
      expireAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
      isActive: { type: DataTypes.ENUM("yes", "no") },
      tags: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
      underscored: true
    }
  );
  return Challenges;
};
```

**Relationship**

```
db.challenges.hasMany(db.sessions, {
  foreignKey: "challenge_id",
  sourceKey: "id"
});
```

Can I perform below SQL query with sequelize Orm model?

```
SET @rank=0

SELECT `challenges`.`*`, `sessions`.*, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank FROM `challenges` JOIN `sessions` ON `sessions`.`challenge_id` = `challenges`.`id` ORDER BY `sessions`.`score` DESC
```

Sequelize support this type of query with it's ORM Model.

Comment: Why not just return `1 AS rank` instead of defining a variable and then incrementing, when its anyways going to return 1 every time you run this query?

Comment: I need rank in order by the score in the session table.